# Scraping the annual dividend yield using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

As  you have probably heard, `getDividends` is no longer working with Yahoo as a source.

So I am trying to get the dividend data by scraping it from a webpage. In particular, I am trying to obtain 2016 year-end yield (2.37) for `MSFT` from the link http://performance.morningstar.com/stock/performance-return.action?p=dividend_split_page&t=MSFT&region=usa&culture=en-US

I installed SelectorGadget and trying to use `rvest` to get the job done. Not having used it before, i tried to follow the instructions and I think `tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(6)` is the information that I need from SelectorGadget to feed to `rvest` but that's where I am getting stuck. I would appreciate any help indicating how to do it.

This is what I've tried:

```
website<-read_html('http://performance.morningstar.com/stock/performance-return.action?p=dividend_split_page&t=MSFT&region=usa&culture=en-US')
website%>%html_nodes('tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(6)')%>%html_text()
```

But the output is:

```
character(0)
```

The ideal output of the code would be:

```
2.37
```

Many thanks.

Comment: This does not appear to be a static page -- you'll have to do dynamic scraping with `RSelenium`.

Comment: @MichaelChirico is there any other way? `RSelenium` appears to depend on a couple of packages that are not avaiable for R version 3.2.3, and updating R is a pain - half of my other external packages will stop working and it's going to take days to fix everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website uses a XHR file to store the information. To download the dividend history try:

```
url<- 'http://performance.morningstar.com/perform/Performance/stock/annual-dividends.action?&t=XNAS:MSFT&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&ops=clear&ndec=2&y=5' 

library(rvest)
#read page
page<-read_html(url)
#find the table and parse it will html_table function
table<-html_node(page, "table")
dividends<-html_table(table)
#remove the blank lines from the final table
dividends[-c(1, 2, 4, 6),]
```

Comment: it works, but the URL has been altered though. So, unfortunately, it does not work for other stocks. For example, if I try to replace `MSFT` with `IBM`, it will no longer work. (for the link <http://performance.morningstar.com/perform/Performance/stock/annual-dividends.action?&t=XNAS:IBM&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&ops=clear&ndec=2&y=5>)

Comment: I think I figured out the solution though, simplifying the link further to <http://performance.morningstar.com/perform/Performance/stock/annual-dividends.action?&t=> and then adding the stock symbol works for any stock. Any disadvantage to that?

Comment: In the address just before the stock symbol is the code for the exchange.  For example in this example XNAS is foe Nasdex while IBM is on the New York stock exchange.